# Creating multiple different factories using the same create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

So I have different factories: factory_1, factory_2
They have different traits trait_1_factory_1, trait_2_factory_1 etc

Is possbile to create factory_1 and factory_2 with specific trairs from the same command, like:

> FactoryBot.create(
>   :factory_1, traits_1_factory_1,
>   :factory_2,
>   :factory_2, traits_1_factory2
>   )

I tried different combinations of () {} [] but doesn't seem to work for me? Is this possbile?
Is this the only solution
Factory.create(:factory_1, traits_1_factory_1)
Factory.create etc.

Thank you

Comment: `Factory.create` or `FactoryBot.create`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possbile to create factory_1 and factory_2 from the same command.

Here, 'factory1' is the `Model` or `class` whose objects are created.

`FactoryBot.create(:factory1)`

If you are doing it for making spec DRY, then rather than doing as above, you can do as below :

```
[
  [:factory_1, traits_1_factory_1],
  [:factory_2, traits_1_factory2]
].each do |factory|
  FactoryBot.create(*factory)
end
```

Store multiple `factories` in `array` and iterate it.

Comment: why the * in *factory

Comment: `*` is to retrieve the elements from an array.
As we need only elements to be passed to the `FactoryBot.create()` than `array`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to create objects using different factories here i.e. when you say `Factory.create`, you mean `FactoryBot.create`.

Unfortunately, i couldn't find any direct command to accomplish such thing. Here is something using a `Hash` and a loop.

```
factories_and_traits = { factory_1: [trait_1_factory_1, trait_2_factory_1],
                         factory_2: [trait_1_factory_2] }

factories_and_traits.each do |factory, traits|
  FactoryBot.create(factory, *traits)
end
```